# Unconfirmed Transaction (after two days)

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees, electrum

Okay, so I have done research on this. My problem is that my fee was embarassingly low. Ive always had my wallet do it automatically and I switched wallets and it was set at .0005 BTC/kb (I didnt check until after a day of no confirmations). Is there any way someone could help me get this transaction confirmed (fee is a whopping 32 cents). Now that I understand how this works, I have set my wallet to manual fee per transaction where I will do $20-30 per transaction for now on. This is extremely embarassing and I meant no disrespect to the miners or the community

https://blockchain.info/tx/c326f5652d7b36a0fb593874714a69b67db3fc810e34b73e0b6eecb087508fb9